# Remove nonalpha, edit, add nonalpha

Tags: python, string

i want to edit a string after removing nonalpha chars, then move them in the proper place again.
eg:

```
import re
string = input()
alphastring = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '', string)
alphastring = alphastring[::2]
```

i want it to be as following:

- string = "heompuem ykojua'rje awzeklvl."
- alphastring = heompuemykojuarjeawzeklvl
- alphastring = hopeyourewell
- ?????? = hope you're well.

I tried fixing the problem with different sollutions but none give me the right output. I resorted to using RegEx which I'm not very familiar with.
Any help would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: `"heompuem ykojua'rje awzeklvl."` to `heompuemykojuarjeawzeklvl` is ok but `hopeyourewell` to `hope you're well.` using regex is impossible

Comment: how could you possibly know what the "proper place" is? how would you determine this?

Comment: There's no general way to know how the original places of the non-alpha characters correspond to their places in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any reasonable way to do this with a regexp. Just use a loop that copies from input to output, skipping every other alphanumeric character.

```
copy_flag = True
string = input()
alphastring = ''
for c in string:
    if c.isalnum():
        if copy_flag:
            alphastring += c
        copy_flag = not copy_flag
    else:
        alphastring += c
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer.. Using 'not' didn't even occur to me.. thank you for this solution.

Comment: If this is the solution, then the question is really poorly worded - Arno should have mentioned that they wanted to remove every second character unless it is not alphanumeric or something similar

Comment: @pygri The slice in the last line of his code gets every other character, and it operates on the result of removing non-alphanumerics.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

```
string = "heompuem ykojua'rje awzeklvl."
result, i = "", 0

for c, alph in ((c, c.isalnum()) for c in string)
    if not (alph and i%2):  # skip odd alpha-numericals
        result += c
    i += alph  # only increment counter for alpha-numericals
 
result
# "hope you're well."
```

Comment: This works, but I wouldn't give it great marks for clarity, it seems like you're worried that we'll run out of newlines.